# can Durbin Watson be used for binary valued times series

Tags: time-series, binary-data, trend, durbin-watson-test

I have multiple time series and for each time series, each series is either one or 0. So for example, it is like the following:

```
id time value
 1  1   1
 1  2   1
 1  3   0
 2  1   1 
 2  2   0
 ...
 ...
```

I am wondering if I want to detect if there is any trend in each of series, what I should do. The first one I think of is to use Durbin-Watson to test for autocorrelation but since the value is binary, I do not know if Durbin-Watson is appropriate. If I do not use Durbin-Watson, what other tests I may use.

To clarify a bit, what I mean by "trend" is to detect if there is some patterns in the values for each id. For example, if gradually, for one id, the value becomes all 0, or all 1, or some persistent alternations of 0 and 1. In other words, supposed a rolling mean for id's values series. I want to know for the rolling mean if there is an increase or decrease trend over time.

Here, in the context, id is user id, and value of 0, 1 means the how a person viewed an object as favorable (1) or unfavorable (0). A person views one object at a time.

Comment: Since autocorrelation is not an indicator of trend (in the usual sense of either word), could you clarify what you mean by "trend"?

Comment: what I am thinking of a trend is that whether there may be some indications that the values for an id in later times become all 0 or all 1 or some pattern..

Comment: Maybe try some (hidden?) Markov model? And please, tell us some context, what does your binary variable represent?  That will increase the probability of a useful answer substantially

Comment: i added the context information